# Set size of inner arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an ArrayList of Arrays:

```
ArrayList<byte[]> arrayOfBytes = new ArrayList <>();
```

I want (and I don't know how) to set a predefined size of the Inner Arrays (the bytes arrays).

Is this possible? If it is, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As in like arrayOfBytes.add(new byte[5]); Here you always wanna add byte array of size of 5 elements ?

Comment: Exactly @Arvind. The thing is that new data would continously come to the list (as a buffer), and I want that data always be an array of a specified size, no more (or less).

Answer (score 2):

The one and only way is to set the size when you're adding those arrays into the list.

```
list.add(new byte[size]);
```

There are no arrays in the List without you explicitly adding them.  Just create the arrays at the right size.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Create a function the returns an array of constant size and use it

```
private byte[] getArray() {
    return new byte[10]();
}
```

The init the inner arrays by calling this function

Answer (score 0):

Your list starts empty, so it has no arrays in it.  Therefore you need to explicitly add them - and as part of doing so, you'll be dimensioning them:

```
final int arraySize = 1024;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  arrayOfBytes.add(new byte[arraySize]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that the inner arrays would be coming in the list (as in a buffer) and I want those be of a specified size, for when I have to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the list is not possible(that information is not relevant for declaring the list itself), but you can define the size when adding a new element to the list

```
arrayOfBytes.add(new byte[size]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I understand. I wanted to specify the size of the arrays for the incoming arrays (stored on the list) that I would be reading. I will not add these.